# How do lme4 in R and MixedModels.jl in Julia initialize model parameters for optimization?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm curious about how lme4 in R and MixedModels.jl in Julia initialize model parameters for optimization.

From page 12 of [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) document

> This template contains three types of elements: structural zeros (denoted by .), off- diagonal covariance parameters (initialized at 0), and diagonal variance parameters (initialized at 1).

it seems like this is how they do it: let's say the model has a random intercept and a random slope, then they would initialize the covariance matrix of the random effects using a 2 by 2 identify matrix. **Question 1: Is my understanding correct?**

By reading the Julia code, it seems like [this](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MixedModels.jl/blob/5fb6f65022c1127d5c4b82d543d9b984b88dc29f/src/linearmixedmodel.jl#L83) is where they initialize. But it seems to me that it only initializes the random effects part, not the fixed effect parameters. **Question 2: Did they just leave the fixed effect parameters uninitialized (so the starting point will be picked by the solver)? Or am I missing anything?**

Answer (score 1):

In linear mixed models, and if you have an estimate for the variance components ($V$ matrix below), the estimator for the fixed effects coefficients has a closed-form. This is why you do not need to initialize these parameters. Namely, if we let $\beta$ denote the fixed effects coefficients, $X$ the fixed-effects design matrix, and $y$ the outcome vector, then we (weighted least squares) estimator is: 
$$\widehat \beta = \Biggl (\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^\top V_i^{-1} X_i \Biggr)^{-1}\Biggl (\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^\top V_i^{-1} y_i\Biggr),$$
where $i = 1, \ldots, n$ denotes the subjects, and $V_i = Z_i D Z_i^\top + \Sigma$, with $Z$ denoting the random effects design matrix, $D$ the variance-covariance matrix for the random effects, and $\Sigma$ the variance-covariance matrix for the error terms.

Comment: So they use REML to estimate V, and then calculate beta_hat using the WLS? But for maximum likelihood, don't they have to estimate beta_hat and V together? That's why I'm puzzled why they don't initialize beta.

Comment: @Xward The WLS for $\beta$ is also the ML estimator. Moreover, the estimators for $\beta$ and $V$ are orthogonal and can be obtained separately. You do not need to estimate them together.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I believe they are orthogonal only if we use REML. For ML, since the log likelihood involves the term (y-X\beta)'V^{-1}(y-X\beta), I don't think one can estimate them separately.